# Add itemReviewed props into woocommerce product loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

On my woocommerce theme I get some errors on Google structured data such as:

[image]

I've found code into mytheme/woocommerce/loop/ratings.php
In this file there are only this method:

```
$product->get_average_rating();
```

The question is: there's a hook or action that implement this function?
I need to implement "ItemReviewed" props.

Answer (score 0):

This is down to your product schema, option one is to remove the error but wont push the reviews is

```
/**
 * Remove the generated product schema markup from Product Category and Shop pages.
 */
function wc_remove_product_schema() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', array( WC()->structured_data, 'generate_product_data' ), 10, 0 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'wc_remove_product_schema' );
```

if you want to aggregate your reviews you will need to update your schema if you are using yoast and woocommerce this can be achieved by looking into the specific yoast woocoommerce plugin and the plugin docs to add the correct schema

https://developer.yoast.com/schema-documentation/woocommerce-seo/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - reviews were not validating and throwing an error

Managed to get it fixed by editing /wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/woocommerce/single-product/review.php

I added the below code:

```
<p>Item Reviewed: <span itemprop="itemReviewed"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span></p>
```

That generated the itemReviewed markup in Structured Data Tool and my reviews validated.

Might want to place it in the child theme just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

define the woocommerce_structured_data_review callback

```py
function filter_woocommerce_structured_data_review( $markup, $comment ) { 
    global $product;

    $markup['itemReviewed']['sku']  = $product->get_sku();
    $markup['itemReviewed']['brand']  = $product->get_attribute( 'brand' ) ?? null;
    $markup['itemReviewed']['description']  = wp_strip_all_tags( do_shortcode( $product->get_short_description() ? $product->get_short_description() : $product->get_description() ) );
    $markup['itemReviewed']['image']  = wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() );
    $markup['itemReviewed']['isbn']  = $product->get_attribute( 'isbn' ) ?? null;
    $markup['itemReviewed']['AggregateRating']  = $product->get_average_rating();

    return $markup; 
};
```

Woocommerce Reviews filter

```py
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_review',
   'filter_woocommerce_structured_data_review', 10, 2 );
```